# Xcode: How-to create a Terminal window inside my application?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, interface-builder, ruby-cocoa

While I am playing with Rubycocoa, I created a small application that works like a charm. However, the only thing missing is like a Terminal inside my application. In Coda, there is a similar kind of view that allows you to open up a terminal session. How would I create a Terminal view like this inside Interface Builder and Xcode?

Thank you for your answers, comments and feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows out that this can be accomplished by using NSTask.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTask

Comment: The link is broken! :O